# select multiple items from second table

Tags: mysql

I have a dB with 2 tables.

The first table is a list of users, the second table is a list of items that belong to that user. For the items, it is one item per row.

Right now, I am doing it very clumsily. I first get the user data, then I get the items and add them to the results from the user data.

Is there a way to get the user data and all of the items in some type of array or other iteratable  format all in one query?

Answer (score 0):

use join operations:

```
 select * from users join userdata on users.userID = userdata.userID
```

where you have a foreign key in the userdata table to your users table

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks. I know about joins. However, I believe, if I use joins and have 20 items, I will get 20 results, one for each item. And each result will have all the user data as well as the item data. I need just the user data once with an entry that contains all the matching items.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help...

Assuming the following:

Table 1: Users

Columns: Id, name, etc

Table 2: Items

Columns: Id, userId, etc

```
select * from users usersWithItems
inner join items userItems on userItems.userId = usersWithItems.id
```